# Add lead from Lightning for Outlook

Tags: lightning, lightning-outlook

I am using [Lightning for Outlook](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/microsoft_integration_admin_set_up_integration_products/units/microsoft_integration_admin_set_up_app_for_outlook_unit_1)

I can create a contact from a selected email (really cool!!!):

[image]

And the new contact fields are auto populated in the new contact:

[image]

The problem is - I cannot add a new lead in the same way.

I have created a publisher action so I can add a new lead (Lead is called a Request in my Org):

[image]

But then I need to populate name, email, phone and all data from the email manually.

Does anybody know if I can add a new lead and populate the email data into it in Lightning for Outlook?